# Put fraction in "arctan-friendly" form

Tags: integration, fractions

I would like to put $\int\frac{1}{(2x^2+x+1)}dx$ into something like $\int\frac{1}{(u^2+1)}dx$. What is the quickest way to proceed? I know that previous fraction can be rewritten as $2t^2+t+1 = \frac{7}{8}\left( \left( \frac{4t+1}{\sqrt{7}} \right)^2 +1 \right)$, but I don't have any explaination from where this comes from.

Finally, the integral yields 
$$\int_b^a \frac{7}{8} \left( \left(\frac{4t+1}{\sqrt{7}} \right)^2+1 \right)dt = \frac{2}{\sqrt{7}}\left[\arctan \left(\frac{4t+1}{\sqrt{7}}\right)\right]^a_b $$

Comment: complete the square

Comment: that was the point, I didn't get how to do it!

Comment: @DenisGantsev: It's definitely surprising to see that someone got all the way to learning about integrals without ever learning about completing the square, which is the basis of the quadratic formula and is taught long before calculus. I'm assuming you merely forget how to do it? Or did they never teach it to you? Also, regardless of the answer, you should really consider reviewing algebra so that these become second nature to you. Otherwise higher-level math will not be friendly!

Comment: I am studying at-distance. I dont have a real teacher, only exercises and answers. Also, I know what's  quadratic formula is, I just didn't know how to use it in this case... whatever, its ok now

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Note that
$$(ax+b)^2=a^2x^2+2abx+b^2$$
Now we want to complete the square on $2x^2+x+1$. We then have $a^2=2, 2ab=1 $ $\implies 4a^2b^2=1 \implies b^2=\frac 1 8$. Thus, we write
$$2x^2+x+1 = \left(2x^2+x+\frac 1 8\right)+\frac 7 8 = \left(\sqrt 2 x+\frac{1}{2\sqrt 2}\right)^2+\frac 7 8$$
Thus, letting $\sqrt2 x+\frac{1}{2\sqrt 2}=\sqrt{\frac 7 8}\tan\theta$, our integral becomes
$$\int \frac{1}{\frac 7 8 \tan^2 \theta+\frac 7 8}\cdot \frac {\sqrt{7}} 4\sec^2\theta d\theta$$

Comment: Thank you! how I can be sure I can discard negative roots from 'a' and 'b' coefficients?

Comment: Since $2ab$ is positive, $a$ and $b$ have to have the same sign. I could have also chosen them to be both negative, but that would have looked messier.

Answer (score 4):

Multiply numerator and denominator by $4\cdot 2=8$ (the $2$ is the coefficient of $x^2$) and “complete the square”:
$$
\frac{1}{2x^2+x+1}=
\frac{8}{16x^2+8x+8}=
\frac{8}{16x^2+8x+1+7}=
\frac{8}{(4x+1)^2+7}
$$
Now you know that you should set $4x+1=u\sqrt{7}$, so you get
$$
\frac{8}{7}\frac{1}{u^2+1}
$$
Moreover, $4\,dx=\sqrt{7}\,du$ and the integral becomes
$$
\int\frac{8}{7}\frac{1}{u^2+1}\frac{\sqrt{7}}{4}\,du=
\frac{2}{\sqrt{7}}\int\frac{1}{u^2+1}\,du=
\frac{2}{\sqrt{7}}\arctan u+c=
\frac{2}{\sqrt{7}}\arctan\left(\frac{4x+1}{\sqrt{7}}\right)+c$$

Comment: +1 for evaluating the integral and avoiding $\tan^2$ & $\sec^2$.